# Anchor a FloatingActionButton with a ListView

Tags: android, listview, floating-action-button

i'm trying to create a list with FAB to have the FAB effect (show/hide) when scroll the list.

The problem is that my ListView and FAB are in different files.

Layout with FAB button:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addForwardFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/custom_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Layout item_list.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:name="mypackage.test.fragment.FItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
    tools:layout="@layout/custom_list_content" />
```

Layout custom_list_content.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When i try to anchor, i got the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find CoordinatorLayout descendant view with id mypackage.test:id/custom_list to anchor view android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

This example works:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <ListView
              android:id="@+id/lvToDoList"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

          <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
              android:layout_margin="16dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
              app:layout_anchor="@id/lvToDoList"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit : The FloatingActionButton cannot find the id it is supposed to be anchored to. And that is because the id is in *custom_list_content.xml* which is referenced only in the *tools:layout* attribute. The *tools* namespace is for design-time only (the IDE can make a preview with the correct content in the fragment in our case) and does not serve for run-time. Basically, at run-time, the layout ends up like this :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/item_list"
            android:name="mypackage.test.fragment.FItemListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addForwardFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/custom_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And so, the FloatingActionButton have no way to find *custom_list*. In the fixed example, everything is put in the same file, including the anchor id, so there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't work with ListViews. You have to use `RecyclerView` instead.

Comment: I edited my post. I put an example that works fine with CoordinatorLayout